# error: invalid operands to binary + (have 'int *' and 'int *')|

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *flot = fopen("input.txt","r");
    int *tab [2001];
    char k[255];
    int i=0;
    while (fscanf(flot, "%s", k) != EOF)
    {
        int b = atoi(k);
        tab[i]=b;
        i++;
    }
    tab[2001]=0;
    int nb = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<1998;i+=3)
    {
        int sum1 = tab[i]+tab[i+1]+tab[i+2];
        int sum2 = tab[i+3]+tab[i+4]+tab[i+5];
        if(sum2>sum1)
            nb++;
    }
    printf("%i", nb);
}
```

The error comes from the 2 sums
I don't remember C forbidding this

Comment: Why are you declaring an array of pointers here `int *tab [2001];`? `tab[2001]=0;` accesses the array out of range and so does the loop that follows. Valid indices for that array are from 0 to 2000.

Comment: You can't add a pointer to a pointer.  Semantically it makes no sense.

Comment: If your compiler didn't give you a warning on this line: `tab[i] = b;`, you should get a newer/better compiler if you possbly can.  C is hard enough to learn, without doing it in a vacuum, without being warning about obvious mistakes like this.  (The mistake in this case is taking an int `b` and stuffing it into an array that has been declared — though evidently wrongly — to hold pointers.)

Comment: What did you think adding two pointers would do?  You can add a pointer and an integer, not two pointers.

Comment: ALWAYS enable your compiler's warnings. e.g. I use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` with gcc & clang. You would have found the problem closer to its root.

Answer (score 0):

C has always forbidden addition (but not subtraction) of pointers. With pointer arithmetic, you can add and subtract pointers and integers

```c
    int *ip = malloc(2 * sizeof *ip);

    printf("where ip points: %p\n", (void *)(ip + 0));
    printf("where ip+1 points: %p\n", (void *)(ip + 1));

    // points one past the last elment in ip's allocation.
    // you can point here, but not dereference the pointer.
    int *jp = ip + 2;
    printf("where jp points: %p\n", (void *)jp);
    printf("where jp-1 points: %p\n", (void *)(jp - 1));
```

(the cast to `void *` in that code is just for the benefit of `printf` where `%p` requires a `void` pointer).

You can also subtract one pointer from another to get how many elements of their underlying type there are between them

```c
    printf("dist from ip to jp: %td\n", jp - ip);
    printf("dist from jp to ip: %td\n", ip - jp);
```

but this is only guaranteed to work if they point into the same allocated block (I forget the technical term, but you are only guaranteed that this will work if it is part of the same array-like allocation, whether on the heap, global or on the stack).

```c
    // This may or may not work (so don't do it)
    int *kp = malloc(5 * sizeof *kp);
    printf("dist from ip to kp: %td\n", kp - ip);
    printf("dist from kp to ip: %td\n", ip - kp);
```

You have never been allowed to add pointers. This should never even compile.

```c
   printf("this doesn't make sense! %p\n", (void *)(ip + jp));
```

When you add or subtract integers, you are only guaranteed that it works if you do not go outside of the allocated block, or point one past the last element in the block. So, if you allocate two integers, like for `ip` above, you can point at the first address, `ip == ip + 0` and at the next integer, `ip + 1`, and you can dereference those. You can also point one past the two blocks, `ip + 2`, (as we did with `jp` above), but you cannot dereference that address. You may or may not get away with addressing outside of this range, but the behaviour is not guaranteed by the standard.

```c
    // You are strictly speaking not allowed to point
    // before your allocation or more than one past.
    printf("where ip-1 points: %p\n", (void *)(ip - 1));
    printf("where ip+3 points: %p\n", (void *)(ip + 3));
```

In your code, you probably do not want

```c
    int *tab [2001];
```

to be an array of pointers, but rather

```c
    int tab [2001];
```

an array of integers. After all, you later treat the elements in the array as integers.

```c
    int b = atoi(k);
  tab[i]=b;
    …
    tab[2001]=0; // although this could be a NULL assignment
    …
    int sum1 = tab[i]+tab[i+1]+tab[i+2];
```